# Opencart reset the password via email

Tags: php, opencart

When a customer clicks *Forgot Password link* and enters their email, an email will be sent to their email address which contains the link,so that they can click on the link and change the password there.

The extension below works, **but how do you make the link expire after password gets updated, and also expires if password was not changed in 24 hours.**

*Link for the extension is:*

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=25484&token=e33958aa296296d09728484f79227785